# How do I make an html block using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'd be grateful if someone could show me how I could create this with jQuery:

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="images/cat6.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
        <h4><b>John Watson</b></h4> 
        <span class="article" id="article_1_intro"></span><span id="article_1" class="article more_text"></span> 
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="read_more">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think some clarification is necessary.  What exactly do you need to do?  And what are you starting with?  jQuery does allow you to insert elements into the DOM, but it also will let you write an html string to an element, too.

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript 6 and other Latest version supports

```
var HTML=`<div class="card">
        <img src="images/cat6.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="container">
            <h4><b>John Watson</b></h4> 
            <span class="article" id="article_1_intro"></span><span id="article_1" class="article more_text"></span> 
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="read_more">Read More</a>
    </div>`;
```

If You have to add some Dynamic Data inside it you can use `${variableName}`
Like This:

```
var IMGSrc="imageURL";
var Name="John Watson";
var HTML=`<div class="card">
            <img src="${IMGSrc}" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>${Name}</b></h4> 
                <span class="article" id="article_1_intro"></span><span id="article_1" class="article more_text"></span> 
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="read_more">Read More</a>
        </div>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use a 3rd party tool;

https://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/

it will ease your effort. so basically you would expect something like this,

```
var myBlock="";
myBlock += "<div class=\"card\">";
myBlock += "    <img src=\"images\/cat6.jpg\" alt=\"Avatar\" style=\"width:100%\">";
myBlock += "    <div class=\"container\">";
myBlock += "        <h4><b>John Watson<\/b><\/h4> ";
myBlock += "        <span class=\"article\" id=\"article_1_intro\"><\/span><span id=\"article_1\" class=\"article more_text\"><\/span> ";
myBlock += "    <\/div>";
myBlock += "    <a href=\"#\" class=\"read_more\">Read More<\/a>";
myBlock += "<\/div>";
```

Now you can play around with **myBlock** variable as you please.

Answer (score 0):

```
var child = '<div class="card">
    <img src="images/cat6.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
        <h4><b>John Watson</b></h4> 
        <span class="article" id="article_1_intro"></span><span id="article_1" class="article more_text"></span> 
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="read_more">Read More</a>
</div>'
```

Let's say you want to add this element as a child to below element,

```
<div id="parent"></div>
```

In jQuery this goes like,

```
$('#parent').html(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").html(
        `<div class="card">
    <img src="images/cat6.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
        <h4><b>John Watson</b></h4> 
        <span class="article" id="article_1_intro"></span><span id="article_1" class="article more_text"></span> 
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="read_more">Read More</a>
</div>`
)
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here is a Simple Solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').html(`<div class="card"><img src="images/cat6.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
            <div class="container">
            <h4><b>JohnWatson</b></4><span class="article" id="article_1_intro"></span>
            <span id="article_1" class="article more_text"></span>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="read_more">Read More</a>
            </div>`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you didn't tell the where do you want to put that HTML code, I assume that it's in the `<body>`. So, you just need `.html()` function from jquery. It will look like this:

```
    $("body").html(
    '<div class="card">
    <img src="images/cat6.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
        <h4><b>John Watson</b></h4> 
        <span class="article" id="article_1_intro"></span><span id="article_1" class="article more_text"></span> 
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="read_more">Read More</a>
    </div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery .append() function. This method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection.[Official Doc](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
  var s = "<div class='card'><img src='images/cat6.jpg' alt='Avatar' style='width:100%'><div class='container'><h4><b>John Watson</b></h4><span class='article' id='article_1_intro'></span><span id='article_1' class='article more_text'></span></div><a href='#' class='read_more'>Read More</a></div>"
    $("#dynamic").append(s);
  });
 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dynamic"><div>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```